# How to change Flink's log directory

Tags: log4j, apache-flink

I understand Flink uses log4j to manage log. So I change log setting in log4j.property, where I set the output location. However, when I start job master, it says that the log location is changed, not the default location. So how could I change the log location of Flink gracefully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default lib directory is set via `bin/config.sh`. Look for `FLINK_LOG_DIR`. You can just update the script to change the default log directory.

Comment: Hello Rock, how did you solve this problem? Did you just just take Matthias's suggestion or is there another way to change log directory, like log4j configure file -- log4j.properties?

Answer (score 5):

Add the following line in `flink-conf.yaml` that can be found in `conf` directory of Flink installation:

```
env.log.dir: /var/log/flink
```

Where `/var/log/flink` is the directory you want to use for logs.

Note that Flink does not seem to support full YML syntax, so

```
env:
  log:
    dir: /var/log/flink
```

will not work!

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.0.3 you can set `env.log.dir` to change the directory where the logs are saved.